# Error en laravel con el proceso de registro de los usuarios

Tags: laravel

Hola estimados amigos de Stack Overflow,

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema cuando intento probar a registrar un usuario nuevo en el script de compra y venta de dominios, páginas webs, redes sociales, servicios virtuales, etcétera... recientemente instalado en el subdominio de https://mercadominios.serviciospromc.eu

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `role_user` (`role_id`, `user_id`) values (2, 2))
https://mercadominios.serviciospromc.eu/register 

Illuminate\Database\Connection::runQueryCallback
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671

Routing

Controller
    App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register
Route name
    unknown
Route parameters
    —
Middleware

        web
        guest
```

Adjunto también el contenido de RegisterController para que podáis revisar el posible error en caso de que fuera necesario:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use App\Role;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users,name'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name'     => $data['name'],
            'email'    => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        $user
            ->roles()
            ->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first());
        return $user; 
    }
}
```

No se si con estos datos alguno de ustedes pueda ayudarme, si se requiere de algo más rogaría me lo hicierais saber.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda y amabilidad.

Comment: Por el mensaje de error, lo primero que miraría es en la tabla role_user de la BD. La columna id es autoincremintal?

Comment: Hola @porloscerros Ψ , lo único que puedo ver en la bd sección role user es: id 32 user_id 1 crerado el, actualizado el, y delete_at NULL. Después hay un apartado dnominado roles donde sparece Admin Role level 5, User role Level 1 y unverified Role level 0. Muchas gracias

Comment: Edita la pregunta, mostrando la estructura de la tabla role_user o en su defecto la migración con la que la creaste. Por lo que comentas falta una columna `role_id` en esa tabla

Comment: También muestra como defines la relación entre User y Role en los modelos